# Publish Gmail Addon Select Extension

Tags: google-apps-script, publish, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-addons, google-console-developer

I am trying to publish Gmail Addon which I create before. I follow that documentation https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish#publish_an_add-on. According the documentation I am reaching the API Console from Resources > Cloud Platform project. And install the Google Apps Marketplace SDK. I cannot save Configuration because of extension selection. I cannot select Gmail Addon extension checkbox. You can see the image [image] Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Cheers.

Comment: Hi! We're still encountering this issue. Is this resolved on your side?

Comment: it's working now. How it solved i don't know. but i guess they fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report. This is due to an issue in the UI, we already have a fix for and should be rolled out soon.
Please note that currently to publish a Gmail add-on the listing has to be domain private or whitelisted, see https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish.

Comment: Hi! Has the fix been rolled out? It's still happening.

Comment: Be aware that Google is currently limiting what Gmail add-ons are permitted to be published publicly. You may not be able to select a Gmail add-on extension with Public visibility until you have filled out the Gmail Add-on Submission Information form here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQD9F5TXZvlpQcY1I6fvaZqLvULG1THhou3y5IpRRwjgwZYg/viewform

That starts the process of getting your add-on whitelist for public publication. Once you're whitelisted, you should be able to complete the publish process.

Comment: @Ryan Roth: How long does this process normally take? I registered on that form 10 days ago and so far I got no reaction...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug on that page. (can't save "Apps Marketplace SDK" Configuration for Gmail Addon). I have [reported it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79123714)

Please, add yourself to "I am also facing this issue" list so that the issue gets noticed by the Google developers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can click Gmail add on extension now.
But after click and fill up Deployment ID,I can't understand how to ''Fill in the Visibility subsection by selecting Public or Private visibility for your add-on.''