# Gmail Addon invisible on iOS Devices

Tags: android, ios, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

A few months ago we developed a Gmail Addon called TeamGram. It's working on web very well and it's working on android and ios devices in Gmail app. Nowadays though the adds on working android devices, we cannot see the addon on ios devices. Some addons like Asana and Trello are working on ios devices but for example Dropbox acts like TeamGram. Do you have any idea about that situation? Why do some add ons get lost suddenly?

Cheers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic [because it should be addressed to Google/Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: According to the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions) GMail Addons are not supported on iOS devices anymore. Rumor has it that Google is in talks with Apple and only a handful of trusted vendors have access to the feature. But (and this is just speculation) with the latest security scare Google may end up scrapping iOS support altogether.

Comment: @I'-'I  According to Google scripting help site (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support) they are using stackoverflow and directly linking here.

We use the popular programming Q&A website Stack Overflow to field technical questions. The site is not run by Google, but you can sign in using your Google account.

Stack Overflow contains questions on a variety of topics, and developers use the tag google-apps-script to mark questions relevant to this service. You may wish add additional tags to your question to attract the attention of experts in related technologies.

Comment: @Nesim Your link also states: ``These channels should only be used for developer issues. Feedback about the core product should be submitted via the Feedback or Report a problem links in the product user interface.`` This  question has nothing to do with development....but about availability in a specific platform.

Comment: @I'-'I  what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752787/publish-gmail-addon-select-extension I guess we can ask that type of questions. Some Googler can see the question on Stackoverflow like AlejandroTamalet who software enginner in Google answered the question which I mentioned at the beginning of my message. You right that it should not be about development but it can be. We just want to understand why the addon is visible now. The Gmail manuel is wrong. In Canada my friends could see the add on in Gmail app on their ios devices but know they don't.