# gmail add-on extension disabled in g suite market place sdk configuration screen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have configured an app script project in script.google.com for developing an gmail calendar add-on. This project is duly linked with a cloud project.

When I am trying to configure G Suite Market Place SDK, "gmail add-on extension" checkbox is disabled under "Extensions".

I have given all the required assets per SDK configuration.

Can anyone please tell me why "gmail add-on extension" is disabled and how it can be fixed?

[image: gmail add-on extension disabled]

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @AhmadHassan yes, the problem was in the Gmail account. The Account should be GSuite account.

Answer (score 0):

Google is currently limiting what Gmail add-ons are permitted to be published publicly. You may not be able to select a Gmail add-on extension with Public visibility until you have filled out the Gmail Add-on Submission Information form here: [Gmail Add-ons Submission form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQD9F5TXZvlpQcY1I6fvaZqLvULG1THhou3y5IpRRwjgwZYg/viewform) That starts the process of getting your add-on whitelist for public publication. Once you're whitelisted, you should be able to complete the publishing process.

Ref link: [answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752787/publish-gmail-addon-select-extension)